# How available is a return to academia for a mid-career professor headed to industry

Tags: job-search, tenure-track, industry, government-institutes

I may leave for industry mid tenure case, with a strong funding and research record. I am hopeful one day to return, and am curious about how commonly such transitions in the industry/government to academe direction happen. I have never been party to one, but I do hear that they happen.  I'd also like to know how to facilitate that option for myself in the future.

I'd like to ask this in the context of the USA, and STEM Research at R1s. My work is multi-disciplinary, and so I could be portable across a number of department types. Possibly some fields do this more than others (Engineering, Business?).

Questions above, but more specifically: how common is this scenario, what might I do to make it more available, what have I not considered.

Comment: Non-vital backstory here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/175327/how-do-i-job-hunt-as-an-assistant-professor-mid-tenure-mid-pandemic